# Git : does the protocol support updating build status?

Tags: git, protocols

Does the git protocol include functionality to add a build status to a commit? A colleague is insistent that it is possible but AFAIK, such functionality is only available in your git tool's API, meaning there is no "generic" method of setting build status.

I can't find anything that states this is either a "git" feature (even if optional) or not.

I tried various documentation pages for the protocol like : https://git-scm.com/docs/protocol-v2 - that suggest the server can advertise extra capabilities and options but doesn't really explain what those capabilities might be. It'd maybe useful if I could run a protocol level command myself and see some responses but I don't see any easy way to do that, I assume one could do something with `openssl s_client`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such protocol capability.

Git commits themselves are immutable: it's not possible to add *anything* to *any* existing commit.  You either make a new commit (that you use in addition to, or instead of, the original), or you live with the existing commit.

Git does have `git notes` and `git log` knows to search for notes that list a commit hash ID as "the commit I am a note for", and display such notes.  Whether that's a solution to your actual problem, I don't know.

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming it would be something like a note that attaches to a commit and marks success/fail. I suppose maybe some "git" app is using a note like "Build xyz : Success"  (probably in JSON!), it doesn't sound like that is a "standard" that you can use on any git GUI app.